# Scoring each letter in a word

Tags: java, beginner, regex

I've made code that scores each letter in a word you input according to the table below:

> 1: AEILNORSTU
>   2: DG
>   3: BCMP
>   4: FHVWY
>   5: K
>   8: JX
>   10: QZ

I appreciate any feedback, but the main reason of this post concerns the `charPoint` method. Should I rewrite this using `switch`? Or is there an even better way to write it?

```
package exercicios;

import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Pattern;

import acm.program.*;

public class Ex5 extends ConsoleProgram{

    public void run(){
        String word = readLine("Enter a word: ");
        println(wordScore(word));

    }

    private int wordScore(String word){
        int score = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            score += charPoint(word.substring(i, i+1));
        }


        return score;
    }
    private int charPoint(String ch){

        if (ch.matches("[AEILNORSTU]")){
            return 1;
        } else if (ch.matches("[DG]")){
            return 2;
        } else if (ch.matches("[BCMP]")){
            return 3;
        } else if (ch.matches("[FHVWY]")){
            return 4;
        } else if (ch.matches("[K]")){
            return 5;
        } else if (ch.matches("[JX]")){
            return 8;
        } else if (ch.matches("[QZ]")){
            return 10;
        } else return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reasoning behind the points? You could try to discover any connection between ASCII code and the letter "value" and avoid the `if..else` or `switch` at all.

Comment: @fracz I think it's the score given in Scrabble for each letter in the word you make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be simpler (and definietly faster when it comes to larger data) to create a `private static final Map<Character, Integer>` with `LETTER -> VALUE` mapping prior to any calculations. Besides repeating the `put` many times when constructing it, you can be even *cooler* although less readable IMO:

```
private static final Map<Character, Integer> LETTER_TO_POINT;

static {
    final Map<Character, Integer> letterToPoint = new HashMap<>();
    // letterToPoint.put('A', 1);
    // letterToPoint.put('B', 3);
    // booooooring :-(

    BiConsumer<String, Integer> rememberPointValues = (letters, points) -> {
        for (char letter : letters.toCharArray()) {
            letterToPoint.put(letter, points);
        }
    };
    rememberPointValues.accept("AEILNORSTU", 1);
    rememberPointValues.accept("DG", 2);
    rememberPointValues.accept("BCMP", 3);
    rememberPointValues.accept("FHVWY", 4);
    rememberPointValues.accept("K", 5);
    rememberPointValues.accept("JX", 8);
    rememberPointValues.accept("QZ", 10);
    LETTER_TO_POINT = Collections.unmodifiableMap(letterToPoint);
}
```

Once you have that, the `charPoint` method is much simpler:

```
private int charPoint(char ch) {
  return LETTER_TO_POINT.get(ch);
}
```

Moreover, you can iterate over the letters in the string [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451660/878514):

```
for (char letter : word.toCharArray()) {
  score += charPoint(letter);
}
```